# How to set class to columns in django model formsets

Tags: python, django, django-forms

have a model and have used it to create model formsets . But i see that formset gives id to each columns like form 0 will have id_0_exp_date then id_1_exp_date etc  but i am looking if there s a way to set class to the columns so all exp_date formsets have same class . I want this behaviour so i can specify jquery and css on these query easily . I couldnt find this in documentation but i feel there should be a way to do that ..

models.py :

```
class Expenditure(models.Model):
    exp_date = models.DateField("Expenditure_Date")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    amount = models.FloatField(default=0)
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=15,default="USD",editable=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('exp_date', 'description',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.description
```

forms.py

```
class ExpenditureForm(forms.ModelForm):

    exp_date = forms.DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget)
    description = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
    amount = forms.FloatField(initial=0)
    currency = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), initial="USD")
"""
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ExpenditureForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.instance.id:
        self.fields['currency'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
"""
# An inline class to provide additional information on the form.
    class Meta:
        # Provide an association between the ModelForm and a model
        model = Expenditure
```

Thanks in advance

Basically I want to make currency field readonly but seems its not working due to some issues or may be i am doing something wrong :

what i tried :
1. currency = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'class':'currencyClass'}), initial="USD")
2. self.fields['currency'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True in form class .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify attributes in your widgets in the forms :

```
class ExpenditureForm(forms.ModelForm):

   exp_date = forms.DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget(attrs={'class':'nameOfYourClass'}))
```

See the full documentation here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/

Comment: I tried this but seems its not working , i want it for currency , this is what i did
currency = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(attrs={'class':'currencyClass'}), initial="USD"), Am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: It is not showing up in your HTML? It's weird, it's working for me and the doc explanation seems rather clear to me: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs. I don't know what could cause your problem

Comment: Can this be because i am using formsets not forms , not sure , just thinking ?

Comment: I think I got it. You are using `forms.ModelForm` instead of `forms.Form`. Basically, it generates the form from your model, and I think it doesn't take into account what you specify before the Meta. Try changing `ModelForm` for `Form`

Comment: I think you are right but this also doesnt seems to work , may be because i am using modelformset_factory and hence its just using my model to create form , is there a way to specify class in model form ?  
ExpFormSet = modelformset_factory(Expenditure,extra=10,max_num=10,fields=('exp_date', 'description','amount','currency'),can_delete=False)

Comment: See this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-form. Try using `ExpFormSet = modelformset_factory(Expenditure,extra=10,max_num=10,can_delete=False, form=ExpenditureForm)`

Comment: Other way to do it : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#specifying-widgets-to-use-in-the-form-with-widgets. (So it means you wouldn't need the ExpenditureForm at all)